# I can't use accents with string in C++

Tags: c++, string

I can set the accents with `SetConsoleOutputCP(1252)` or `locale::global(locale"FR-fr")`, but I can't use it with strings. Seems like it's one or the other. I can output text with accents, or I can output the string with accents, not both. Any ideas?

The code below can be used to reproduce the problem. Simply add `locale::global(locale"FR-fr")` or `SetConsoleOutputCP(1252)`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   string mot;
   cout << "Inscrivez un mot avec des accents (é ou è): ";
   cin >> mot;
   cout << mot;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you set both the [input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolecp) and [output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsoleoutputcp) code pages:

```
SetConsoleCP(1252);       // input
SetConsoleOutputCP(1252); // output
```

Comment: Seems to be working! Thanks for the fast answer!